# Counting principle with constrained repetition

Tags: combinatorics

This is a very basic question but i m not able to grasp.

In a question psper if thete are 3 maths and 2 english questions than in how many outcome of 2 questions possible if repetition is allowed but you can't choose the same question twice.

i came up  with an answer of 8 .

Comment: If you are allowed to choose any $2$ of the $5$ questions then the number of options is $C(5,2)=10$.